.NET Maui Binding Warning, "LoginCommand" property not found on LoginPageViewModes
I am following a tutorial from AshProgHelp to build a simple loginpage for my windows app.
In part 2 minute 9:15 values are placed in the input fields of the username and password, Followed by a login.
When I try the same, nothing happens with the sign in button.
When examining the output log I find the following compile warning:

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'LoginCommand' property not found on 'MyAdministrationApp.Viewmodes.LoginPageViewModes', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button.Command'

Below is the .cs code
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MyAdministrationApp.Models;
using MyAdministrationApp.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MyAdministrationApp.Views;

namespace MyAdministrationApp.Viewmodes
{
    public partial class LoginPageViewModes : BaseViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _userName;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _password;

        readonly LoginRepository loginRepository= new LoginService();

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task LoginCommand()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sign In button pressed");
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName ) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password))
            {
                UserInfo userInfo = await loginRepository.Login(UserName, Password);

                if (Preferences.ContainsKey(nameof(App.UserInfo)))
                {
                    Preferences.Remove(nameof(App.UserInfo));
                }

                string userDetails = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userInfo);
                Preferences.Set(nameof(App.UserInfo), userDetails);
                App.UserInfo = userInfo;

                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
            }
        }

    }
}

The LoginPage Class.
using MyAdministrationApp.Viewmodes;

namespace MyAdministrationApp;

public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage(LoginPageViewModes loginPageViewModes)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = loginPageViewModes;

    }
}

and the XAML code
      <Button Text="Sign In" BackgroundColor="#58D68D" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" CornerRadius="30" WidthRequest="200" Margin="0,15,0,0" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,60,0,0" Padding="0">
            <Label Text="New User?" TextColor="DarkGray" FontSize="Small" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
            <Label Text="Sign Up" TextColor="#1D8348" FontSize="Small"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>

I've tried adding the property manually by adding this to the loginpageviewmodes
public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }
public LoginPageViewModes()
{
    LoginCommand = new Command(OnLogin);
}

private void OnLogin()
{
    //Same code as in LoginCommand
}

This provided me with more errors,
The code should simply check if both input fields are not 'black' and then, upon pressing the sign in button. Should navigate to the next page.
I am a beginner with .NET Maui.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!.


Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'LoginCommand' property not found on 'MyAdministrationApp.Viewmodes.LoginPageViewModes', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button.Command'

This warning show the binding command is failed. This because you used both [RelayCommand] attribute and named the method as LoginCommand()
Please change the public async Task LoginCommand() to public async Task Login(). The [RelayCommand] will auto make the Login method be Login Command. Such as:
[RelayCommand]
public async Task Login()
{

For more information, you can read the official document about how does the [RelayCommand] attribute work.
